# Best Azure Service for Large no of SQLServer Databases

Tags: sql-server, azure

We have a dedicated SQL Server Machine for a SAAS application with about 200+ databases, the server has E5-2620 with 64 GB RAM, Now we want to move all the databases to the Azure, so for looking into the options we can either go with a Virtual Machine like (DS13 v2) which can support all these DBs or can use the Azure SQL Elastic Pools like Standard with 400 eDTUs.

My Question is that in the Long Run and from management and scalability point of view which option is better, and also will the Standard Elastic Pool with 400 eDTU's can provide the same performance as the Virtual Machine?

One of the major concerns for us is the performance of the SQL DBs in Azure, as this is one of the reason to move the whole application to the Azure so that in the future as the no of users grow we can easily upgrade our instances to cater the increased load.

Answer (score 4):

> My Question is that in the Long Run and from management and scalability point of view which option is better

For "management and scalability" Azure SQL Database is clearly better.

Azure SQL Database was designed for this scenario.  You can spread out your databases across multiple pools, as needed, or move specific databases to non-pooled DTUs.  And Azure SQL Database has built-in patching, HA/DR, monitoring, and backup.

Azure Virtual Machines give you way more flexibility to design SQL Servers that *exactly* fit your needs, but that comes with a cost of complexity and management.

In both cases you should plan to spread your databases out over a few Elastic Pools / VMs, so you can scale out as well as up.